# How to set default resolution in YouTube app?

Tags: youtube

Such that every time I open a YouTube video, it opens on that resolution. It is annoying when it changes automatically according to the network, and for every video, I have to change the resolution.

How to set default resolution in YouTube app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube app doesn't have this feature. However, [YouTube Vanced](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-youtube-vanced-edition-t3758757) comes with this feature. Go into its Settings - > Vanced Settings - > Video settings, and configure the resolution for both Wi-Fi and Mobile data separately.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

According to the official YouTube product document, the video player do remember the settings done by user,

Below is the Note mentioned on the [official page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/91449?hl=en)

> Note: Choosing lower video quality (such as 240p and 360p) will make
>   videos start more quickly. The video player will remember this setting
>   for future videos you watch.

So essentially, you need to follow the below steps...

To adjust video quality while watching on your mobile device:

[image]

In this page, it is only mentioned as Mobile device and it does not say the YouTube App.

However, I myself did tried the above steps, and I found that YouTube Player remembered my previously set video quality setting.

Answer (score 0):

Except, what is not noted on the FAQ page is that "fully" closing the YouTube app by "home button then swiping it away", closing web browser and clearing cache, or restarting the device will revert YouTube back to its default behavior of:

1. The speed of your Internet connection
2. Video player/screen size: Higher quality videos generally play better on larger screens.
3. Quality of the original uploaded video: If the video was recorded in standard definition, it won’t be available in high definition.

Setting a persistent default video quality is no longer possible.

However, this setting has been added for Android to the custom YouTube Vanced app if you're brave enough to sideload apps in Android.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-youtube-vanced-edition-t3758757